# Disabling prevent.Default action

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript code which initiates mobile menu dropdown. But while I was working on this, I wasn't paying attention and stupidly copied a code from another source and now I can't click on parent items on mobile menu.

When I remove `e.preventDefault();`, I'm getting an error in console and menu is not working. Here is the full code. What can I do with my code to make the parent items clickable?

```
            var $dropdownOpener = $('.mobile-header-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a');
            
            if ($dropdownOpener.length) {
                $dropdownOpener.each(function () {
                    var $thisItem = $(this);
                    
                    $thisItem.on('tap click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        
                        var $thisItemParent = $thisItem.parent(),
                            $thisItemParentSiblingsWithDrop = $thisItemParent.siblings('.menu-item-has-children');
                        
                        if ($thisItemParent.hasClass('menu-item-has-children')) {
                            var $submenu = $thisItemParent.find('ul.sub-menu').first();
                            
                            if ($submenu.is(':visible')) {
                                $submenu.slideUp(450);
                                $thisItemParent.removeClass('qodef--opened');
                            } else {
                                $thisItemParent.addClass('qodef--opened');
                                
                                if ($thisItemParentSiblingsWithDrop.length === 0) {
                                    $thisItemParent.find('.sub-menu').slideUp(400, function () {
                                        $submenu.slideDown(400);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    $thisItemParent.siblings().removeClass('qodef--opened').find('.sub-menu').slideUp(400, function () {
                                        $submenu.slideDown(400);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to call e.originalEvent.preventDefault() with null checks like :

```
e && e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.preventDefault()
```